# allow navigation whitelist is not tested first on "UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked" event on Cordova iOS@4.0.0

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am creating a sample application to evaluate Cordova ios@4.0.0 with Cordova 5.4.1 and now encountered an issue.

My sample app intends to access https://www.google.co.jp/* in the webview and opens system browser when accessed to other domains.

Below is the sample code I wrote.

・index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
 // open google on start up.
    var ref = window.open("https://www.google.co.jp", '_self', 'location=no');
    </script>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

・config.xml

```
...
<access origin="*" requires-forward-secrecy="false" />
<!-- Added google.co.jp to allow open in webview -->
<allow-navigation href="https://www.google.co.jp/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
...
```

I understand that we can access the domain or URL which is defined in `<allow-navigation>` tags in the webview.
And if not, Cordova opens the system browser (e.g. Safari, android browser or so on) when those are defined in `<allow-intent>` tags.

But on ios@4.0.0, the system browser opened when I tapped a link under Google domain e.g. https://www.google.co.jp/imghp.
(This code worked fine for me on android@4.1.1. on the other hand)

I found out finally that I have to hack the obj-c native code which ios@4.0.0 provides.

In CDVIntentAndNavigationFilter.m, allow navigation whitelist was tested after allow intent whitelist when UIWebviewNavigationTypeLinkClicked event occurred.
So I added the code to test allow navigation whitelist first.

・CDVIntentAndNavigationFilter.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldOverrideLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request     navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL* url = [request URL];

    switch (navigationType) {
        case UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked:
            // Note that the rejection strings will *only* print if
            // it's a link click (and url is not whitelisted by <allow-*>)

            // FIXME suppose we should test the navigation whitelist first
            // ↓↓ this code not exists in cordova iOS@4.0.0 at this moment
            if ([self.allowNavigationsWhitelist URLIsAllowed:url]) {
                // the url is in the <allow-navigation> tag, so we can navigate to this url
                return YES;
            }
            // ↑↑ this code not exists in cordova iOS@4.0.0 at this moment

            if ([self.allowIntentsWhitelist URLIsAllowed:url]) {
                // the url *is* in a <allow-intent> tag, push to the system
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
                return NO;
            }
            // fall through, to check whether you can load this in the webview
        default:
            // check whether we can internally navigate to this url
            return ([self.allowNavigationsWhitelist URLIsAllowed:url]);
    }
```

I'm not sure about this issue is a bug or not. If it is, I will try to report an issue to the community, and if not, is there any workarounds to avoid this issue without hacking framework Cordova provides?